# Tengo un problema con e.target.value, me devuelve valores desactualizados

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
function search(e) {
    console.log('click')
    console.log(e.target.value)
    let value = e.target.value;
    let all = document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-keywords]");

    for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
      let keywords = all[i].getAttribute("data-keywords");

      let match = keywords.indexOf(value);

      if (match === -1) {
        all[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        all[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }

}

document.getElementById("search-bar").addEventListener("keydown", search);
```

Necesito obtener el valor de un input para hacer una búsqueda dinámica en una lista con cada tecla presionada. Este es mi input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Busca envento..." id="search-bar">
```

El problema está en que `e.target.value` me devuelve el valor desactualizado. Por ejemplo, cuando ingreso una letra `console.log(e.target.value)` está vacío, luego con la segunda sólo imprime la primera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de obtener el valor actualizado?

Agradecería mucho si me ayudaran. Ya he buscado en muchos sitios.

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de al evento `keydown`, *enganchate* al evento [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

```
document.getElementById("search-bar").addEventListener("change", search);
```

El evento `keydown` se lanza, como indica su nombre, al **pulsar** una tecla, pero **antes de soltarla**. Con lo cual estás pidiendo el contenido antes de que realmente se produzca la alteración del mismo.

<sub>Nota: También pueden consultar el evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)</sub>